# Enterprise Library Logging Block not logging events in Web-Api MVC 4 Azure Web role

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-roles, enterprise-library-5

I am having some issue with Logging events in Application log in Web Api Web role in Azure environment.

When debugging in Local machine I am able to log all events in my event log but once hosting the same application in Azure environment no events are logging and there are no errors.
I have used same configuration and code in Worker role project and it is working fine without any issues.

Is there any specify configuration do I need to do for Web Api MVC applications?
I am running my Web role in Elevated mode, and also provided permission on Event Source through ‘regedit’ but still no events are writing in Application log.